# How to obtain ongoing user consent for use of location info

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, core-location

In my application, I'm using location information to capture the user locations.
I have the following questions:

1. What are the alert messages we have to provide in the application for user to show that we are going to use their location?
2. Can we fetch the location info in the background once the user accept that?
3. If user is allowed to fetch the location information let's say in the first time the application launches, do we need to provide the alerts for consecutive fetches (in next app loads)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. None, iOS will do this automatically.
2. This is the normal procedure.
3. iOS will bug the user as it is programmed to do.

Answer (score 3):

If you assign the `purpose` property to your location manager instance, it will include that in the popup that asks the user for permission. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW30

Yes for the other two.

Comment: Thanks this is needed also. Thanks for your reply Matt.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an iPhone programmer, but I'm an iPhone user.  Every time an application has asked for access to my location information, once I say yes it never asks again and regularly uses it.

This leads me to believe that the answer to your questions is:

1) Probably the alert message is provided automatically the first time your application requests location information.  I'm pretty sure they aren't relying on developers policing themselves.

2) Yes, I believe so.

3) Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Yes thanks for the reply Mike. Daniel has also a similar answer like you.